# Kafka Streams fails on startup

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I use Kafka Streams with one 5-partitioned input topic ("input_topic"), but have many repartitions.
Most of the time it works just fine.

However, sometimes, when I restart the service (2 instances of the application), I get the following error on each of the StreamThreads:

```
ERROR o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread.run - stream-thread [my-app-7c367779-f563-4944-9e2f-095c37e3664d-StreamThread-2] Encountered the following error during processing:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Assigned partition my-app-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000046-repartition-3 for non-subscribed topic regex pattern; subscription pattern is input_topic|my-app-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000004-repartition|my-app-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000012-repartition|my-app-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000024-repartition|my-app-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000033-repartition|my-app-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000044-repartition|my-app-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000058-repartition|my-app-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000067-repartition|my-app-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000076-repartition|my-app-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000086-repartition
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState.assignFromSubscribed(SubscriptionState.java:187)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:250)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:406)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:340)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:341)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1214)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1179)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1164)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:913)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:818)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:777)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:747)
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Do you have any direction to investigate?

Thanks!

Comment: some issue with internal Kafka topic. have you changed the number of partitions or some configs that might affect it?

Comment: No... I didn't.

Comment: What version are you using? Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: I use version 2.1.0 :(